rendering mode problem + scene balls
I'm very new to Blender.
As soon as I press rendering mode it’s turning the default box to black, the monkey too.
How can I fix that?
Also I think they way the scene “balls” layout is off


Firstly check that your graphics driver is up to date and that your graphics card is compatible with Blender 4.2. - Your node group gives me a top-to-bottom gradient on Suzanne with a better result if you plug the Texture Coordinate Object output rather than the Generated one into the Seperate XYZ node . By "Scene balls" I assume you mean that they are reversed compared to any tutorial you are following? - For some reason their positions have been swapped since Blender 3.6 but that's purely a layout change.
